# Trac SvnAuthzAdminPlugin not showing users

Tags: python, trac, ubuntu

I'm using [Trac v0.12.2](http://trac.edgewall.org/) with the [SvnAuthzAdminPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SvnAuthzAdminPlugin) and [AccountManagerPlugin](http://www.fire-proxy.com/trac-hacks.org/wiki/AccountManagerPlugin). I'm sharing a HtDigest auth file between Trac and Apache/Svn.

**trac.ini**

```
[trac]
authz_file = /trac/svnaccess
repository_type = svn

[account-manager]
password_store = HtDigestStore
password_file = /trac/trac.htdigest
htdigest_realm = TracRealm

[components]
acct_mgr.web_ui.LoginModule = enabled
trac.web.auth.LoginModule = disabled
acct_mgr.admin.AccountManagerAdminPages = enabled
acct_mgr.htfile.HtDigestStore = enabled
acct_mgr.pwhash.htdigesthashmethod = enabled
svnauthz.* = enabled

[svnauthzadmin]
show_all_repos = true
```

For some reason, all users show up in the AccountManagerPlugin's Users menu, but only the TRAC_ADMIN user shows up in the SvnAuthzAdminPlugin select box for adding users to a group. Everything else works exactly the way it should and I can manually add entries to my `svnaccess` file. I know it's something small because I've had it working before with, what I thought was, the exact same configuration.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this ticket](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/5191) filed against the svnauthz plugin, it looks like this may be a limitation in the plugin itself.  According to a comment on that ticket:

> The list of users that is shown comes from the list of users (or
>   groups) in Trac that have been assigned at least one permission.
>
> So, if you want to give one person specific access in svn authz, they
>   need to have at least one permission explicitly granted to them in the
>   Trac permissions; they can't have their only permissions come from
>   Trac group membership.

Try explicitly assigning a permission to a few user accounts and see if they show up in the list.  If that seems to work, then you may want to consider re-building the plugin from source and applying one of the two patches described in that ticket (the [second patch](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/5191#comment:6) listed seems more straightforward IMO).